# How to throw an error message to the client when check() throws an Match.Error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception, meteor

I am publishing some documents from the `Products` collection, and using [`check()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check) to ensure the options passed to it are valid. If the client passes in invalid options, I want to have a customized error message displayed on the console.

I am using the [`audit-argument-checks`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks) package to ensure I have checks for all methods and publish functions.

On the client, I passed in an invalid option (`reverse` should be a boolean), but no errors are observed on the client console nor the server log.

```
// Server
Meteor.publish('products', function (opts) {
    try {
        check(opts, {
            sort: Match.Optional(String),
            reverse: Match.Optional(Boolean),
            start: Match.Optional(Number),
            limit: Match.Optional(Number),
            userId: Match.Optional(String)
        });
    } catch (err) {
        this.error(new Meteor.Error('invalid-opts', "Please check your options are valid")); // Throws back an error saying invalid options
    }
    // Some more code
});

// Client
Template.home.helpers({
    productListings: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('products', {sort: 'created', reverse: 'asdasd'});
        return Products.find({});
    }
});
```

I have tried using [`Match.test()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/match_test) in place of `check()`, but this does not satisfy the `audit-argument-checks` package, and I'd want to use it to ensure I don't miss any checks.

How can I throw an error message to the client when `check()` throws an `Match.Error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you are just failing to check for the error with a callback on the client.  See the [`onError` callback of `Meteor.subscribe()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe).

I have done your subscribe as below [in a Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/wQq5aEiP7THqZQ2z9/publish%20error) and it goes to the client for handling as expected.

```
Meteor.subscribe('products',{sort: 'created', reverse: 'asdasd'},
  {onError: function( err ) {throw err;}}
);
```

Comment: Additionally, the check block does not have to be in a try catch since it will always throw a Match.Error which will propagate to the onError callback.

Comment: user7282791 That worked for me thanks! @Serkan, if I didn't do the try catch block I cannot specify the error message.

Comment: You are providing a very generic invalid-opts error message, therefore instead of using the try catch block, I think you should handle the Match error that returns to the client on the client, in your error callback. If you want to tell the user which field exactly is the problematic one, then you can do individual checks against each option and wrap that in try/catch.